# Triangulated categories vs stable infinity categories

Tags: soft-question, homological-algebra, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

It is well known that the associated homotopy categories of Lurie's stable infinity categories are triangulated categories. In most cases (i.e. excluding some special cases of triangulated categories without models) this is how the triangulated structure arises.

In light of the relative simplicity of stable infinity categories compared to triangulated categories, at least in writing down the basic definitions, when is it preferable to use one over the other? My question is focused primarily on the case of (subcategories of) the derived category of complexes of sheaves on a space (or site).

Comment: If you think that stable infinity categories are simpler than triangulated categories, then go for them. I would say that infinity categories are better since they are the "true" categories to consider, they don't loose information, (co)limits have a meaning there... but one uses triangulated categories because they are much easier (and in particular they are ordinary categories !)